# What is the proper way to write a computed property using TypeScript and Ember?

Tags: typescript, ember.js

I have a relatively small Ember/TypeScript app that I have been working on for about six months. I used to define computed properties as follows:

```
   @computed('styleNamespace', 'status')
   statusClass(componentClassName: string, status: string): string {
     return `${componentClassName}--${status}`
   }
```

But I have never been able to get this to pass TypeScript checking properly. After reviewing Chris Krycho's [Emberconf training materials](https://github.com/chriskrycho/emberconf/blob/master/app/components/todo-list.ts#L19), it seems that the "proper" way to do this is as follows:

```
   @computed('styleNamespace', 'status')
   get statusClass(this: CertificateCard): string {
     return `${this.get('styleNamespace')}--${this.get('status')}`
   }
```

Is this correct? I seem to be missing something, though because I am still getting errors like this:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Attempted to apply @computed to statusClass,
but it is not a native accessor function. 
Try converting it to `get statusClass()`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make decorators work with TypeScript in Ember.js, you'll need to use at least ember-decorators 2.0.0 (available at the time of this answer as `2.0.0-beta.2`) and set `"experimentalDecorators": true` in the `"compilerOptions"` section of your `tsconfig.json`.

Then, for all versions of Ember prior to 3.1 you'll write computeds like so (as in your second example, but written out more fully for anyone else who stumbles on this later). Note that we don't need the return type for the getter, as it can be properly inferred by TypeScript (unlike classic Ember computed property callbacks, where the return type *was* required to be explicit).

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember-decorators/object';

export default class TheComponent extends Component {
   styleNamespace: string;
   status: string;

   @computed('styleNamespace', 'status')
   get statusClass() {
     return `${this.get('styleNamespace')}--${this.get('status')}`
   }
}
```

Starting with Ember 3.1, which stabilizes [Ember RFC #281](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0281-es5-getters.md), you'll be able to further simplify this by dropping `this.get` for *any* property which does not involve [Proxies](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/ObjectProxy). Note that you'll also be able to drop the `this` type declarations then.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember-decorators/object';

export default class TheComponent extends Component {
  styleNamespace: string;
  status: string;

  @computed('styleNamespace', 'status')
  get statusClass() {
    return `${this.styleNamespace}--${this.status}`;
  }
}
```

(As an aside: if the properties are known not to be computed properties, but are e.g. simple strings passed into the component at construction time, you can do this even prior to Ember 3.1.)

---

Regarding any possible concerns about the future and stability of the decorators proposal: no proposed changes to the spec will have an impact on the *consumers* of the decorators we're using in Ember.js. They will require implementors (e.g. the team working on the ember-decorators project) to make changes, but consuming code (i.e. in regular apps and addons) will be unaffected.

Comment: I'm a little confused here, @chris-krycho. It seems that your version of the cp code and my version are identical. I have ember-decorators up to version 2.0.0-beta.1 already (will upgrade to 2.0.0-beta.2). My Ember is slightly old (version 2.16), so perhaps I should upgrade it?

Comment: I have not confirmed on 2.16, but would expect it to work correctly there. I have confirmed on 2.17.2 as well as the 3.1 beta series. Also, confirm that you have a `get` function, as the error *seems* to be suggesting that's the problem.

Comment: Okay, this is now working. Not completely sure what the fix was, as I did, in fact upgrade to Ember 3.1 as part of the solution. Thanks for your help!